# How to make Enumerator not from file?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm developing web application with scala + play 2.0.4. When the program runs, it fetches huge amount of data from mongoDB and tries to make csv file and send it to client browser so that the csv file is supposed to be downloaded. But the data was so big that browser couldn't wait for a long time without any response. I tried to use Ok.stream() and Enumerator but I don't know how to use it and handle this problem. Could you tell me how to fix this problem by using Ok.stream and Enumerator?